# Get a twilio phone number SID, at a later date, if you don't capture it when you purchase twilio number

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

Is there any easy way to get a phone number SID, at a later date, if you don't capture it when you purchase twilio number.

It is easy to capture a phone number sid when purchasing number, but solutions I found for capturing it at later date seem complicated and use loops.

Capturing Phone Number SID when buying number:

```
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = 'accountsid'
auth_token = 'your_auth_token'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

# Purchase the phone number
number = client.incoming_phone_numbers \
               .create(phone_number=number)

print(number.sid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with "exact match".

For example, if your number is `+17775553333`, try this code to get the `sid`.

```py
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
auth_token = 'your_auth_token'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

incoming_phone_numbers = client.incoming_phone_numbers.list(phone_number='+17775553333', limit=20)

for record in incoming_phone_numbers:
    print(record.sid)
```